# Is it possible to have the menu bar in the title bar in Ubuntu Flashback mode?

Tags: 14.04, gnome

I've never used Unity, but I came across this cool Unity feature of having the menu bar in title bar. I'm talking about this:

http://arstechnica.com/information-technology/2014/02/ubuntu-desktop-moving-application-menus-back-into-application-windows/

Is this possible in Ubuntu Flashback?

EDIT: I'm not talking about the global menu here. See the link above. I'm looking for each window having its own menu bar, and that which resides in each window's title bar. `apt-get install indicator-applet-appmenu` does indeed get me the global menu, but I'm not looking for that.

Comment: Thanks for the help, mchid, but I'm looking for per window local menu bars, not the global menu.

Comment: You question is confusing...
Ask it clearly !

Answer (score 2):

The simple answer to orig. ?  is No.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're looking for? [Local Menu Bar](http://www.howtogeek.com/187999/how-to-enable-local-menus-in-ubuntu-14.04/)

It sums up to going to Settings > Appearance > Behavior, then there's a radio button at the bottom that lets you toggle the local menu on and off. It doesn't let you have both though, I'm not sure if you wanted just one or the other, or both.

Comment: Unfortunately that radio button doesn't do anything in Flashback mode.

Comment: I'm struggling to find a command line option that works (found one that didn't for me),  but I did find a setting in dconf editor if you haven't tried that yet. There's a checkbox for "integrated-menus" under: com > canonical > unity. Had an instant effect for me, granted I'm not using Flashback mode.

Comment: That dconf config is the same setting as Settings > Appearance > Behavior radio button. If you open up dconf and the Settings > Appearance > Behavior screen you can see that toggling one changes the other. Neither one works in Flashback mode though unfortunately. Thanks for your help though. I really appreciate it.

Comment: Yeah, no problem. Sorry I haven't been able to find anything else for it unfortunately. I don't remember where I found the command line thing that didn't work for me, I did find one person have success by just uninstalling the global menu by using "sudo apt-get remove indicator-appmenu" though you mileage may vary haha. I'm guessing the idea was to force it to use the local menu, the page said it works from 12.04 through 14.04 though. Author also notes that some applications, like Firefox, have to have the setting changed within the application itself.